# C compiler directives with switch/case statements?

Tags: c, switch-statement, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

What do I do with this switch-case statement in **C**?

```
#if defined MY_CONST && define RUN_TEST
    case TX_ERROR:
        //code here
        break;
    case RX_ERROR:
        //other code here
        break;
#endif
```

I'm coding in an existing project, and I see the above lines in an included header file (in the file I'm working on). No mention of a "switch" anywhere else in the header file!

I've never seen this before! How can these be case switches without the switching? Since this must be possible, how can I use these cases in a switch statement in my main file?

EDIT: I can't post the actual file (code base under licence?), but here's a stripped version:

```
#if defined _CONFIG
    #define MY_CONST
    #define MY_INIT
    #define RUN_TEST

    static void fnInit(void);
    static void fnGo(void);
#endif

#if defined MY_CONST && define RUN_TEST
    case TX_ERROR:
        //code here
        break;
    case RX_ERROR:
        //other code here
        break;
#endif

#if defined MY_INIT && defined MY_CONST
static void fnInit(void)
{
    //code
}

static void fnGo(void)
{
    //code
}
#endif
```

Comment: Is that the entire content of the header file? Perhaps its meant to be `#include`d from within a `switch`.

Comment: There's other `#ifdefs` in the header too, one of them having two functions defined inside! Having the `#include` in a `switch` makes sense, but then how would it handle the functions??

Comment: I note, years later, that the line `#if defined MY_CONST && define RUN_TEST` is ill-formed; it should use `defined` twice: `#if defined MY_CONST && defined RUN_TEST`.  I don't know the implications of that.  I wonder if it should be more like `#if defined MY_CONST` — ```#define RUN_TEST \``` — with backslashes at the end of subsequent lines to make a macro.  But it isn't very nice code, regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that `MY_CONST` is never defined!

If what you quote is accurate, then you'd have to include the header in the scope of a `switch` statement for the result with `MY_CONST` defined to make any sense.  If it is not embedded in a macro, then it is basically an accident waiting to happen.

---

With the revised content, make sure that you never have both `MY_CONST` and `RUN_TEST` defined.  There is no way for the header to be used sanely if they are -- not even if you are using GCC and have nested functions enabled.

Fundamentally, that fragment is a bug in the header.